# Java not equals with OR

Tags: java

I'm just wondering why this is not correct :

```
if ( !name.equals("abc") || !name.equals("cba") )`
```

And this is correct :

```
if ((!(name.equals("abc") || name.equals("cba") )))
```

thank you !

Comment: They do not mean the same thing.

Comment: I suggest you take an example of `name`, and think about what each part of the expression will evaluate to.

Comment: First condition will always return true as both the operands contradict each other.

Comment: This is basic logic. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: *If name does not equal A or does not equal B* - it can't equal both at once, so is always true. — *Reverse of "name equals A or B"* - clearly a more sensible condition.

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies ! And it is not a matter of openning eyes, I'm just a beginner and I thought that it was a problem related to the code so I focussed on it. It is not because it is obvious for somebody at first sight that it is for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the difference, it always helps to read out your condition statement in english.

```
if ( !name.equals("abc") || !name.equals("cba") )
```

Translates to

> If name does not equal "abc" OR name does not equal "cba", then...

Whereas,

```
if ((!(name.equals("abc") || name.equals("cba") )))
```

> If (name equals "abc' OR name equals "cba" ) IS FALSE, then...

or, by Boolean Logic,

> If name does not equal "abc" AND name does not equal "cba", then...

The two are definitely not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the `!` works.

Take `!(a || b)`

whats the truth table:

```
a=f b=f = !(f || f) = !(f) = t
a=f b=t = !(f || t) = !(t) = f
a=t b=f = !(t || f) = !(t) = f
a=t b=t = !(t || t) = !(t) = f
```

Now take `(!a || !b)`

```
a=f b=f = (!f || !f) = (t || t) = t
a=f b=t = (!f || !t) = (t || f) = t
a=t b=f = (!t || !f) = (f || t) = t
a=t b=t = (!t || !t) = (f || f) = f
```

Now take the correct way to distribute  `!` `(!a && !b)`

```
a=f b=f = (!f && !f) = (t && t) = t
a=f b=t = (!f && !t) = (t && f) = f
a=t b=f = (!t && !f) = (f && t) = f
a=t b=t = (!t && !t) = (f && f) = f
```

And for completeness sake take the same as `(!a || !b)` `!(a && b)`

```
a=f b=f = !(f && f) = !(f) = t
a=f b=t = !(f && t) = !(f) = t
a=t b=f = !(t && f) = !(f) = t
a=t b=t = !(t && t) = !(t) = f
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code has this truth table

[image]

The second code instead has this truth table

[image]

Comment: Do you think this truth table is correct? Can you give me a case for which first condition has false value?

Comment: It was wrong. The online software I used is not working properly. Now I've corrected it. Thanks @SanketMakani

Comment: Still if you look conditions closely there are only three cases possible for both the condition. `a` and `b` can't be true at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a math question. These are same logical equation:

```
!x || !y  ==  !(x && y)
!x && !y  == !x || !y
```

You can read more about logical operation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)